# PHP Xdebug stopped working via cookie

Tags: php, vagrant, xdebug

At least I *think* that's what is going on.

I've been using Xdebug with PhpStorm for months without an issue and then just recently it's stopped working.

I thought I had it fixed by changing the port from 9000 to 9003, but I've tried to recreate this "fix" on another machine and I'm back to square one.

PhpStorm is configured correctly. Using Postman I can set the session start with the key name and it triggers xdebug within PhpStorm (`?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=vagrant`). PhpStorm's validation also returns back as being set correctly.

I'm using the Chrome Xdebug helper extension that sets the cookie `XDEBUG_SESSION`, as always, but it's simply not triggering in the code.

Here is the config that's always worked for me:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_connect_back=true
xdebug.idekey=vagrant
```

EDIT:

I definitely think this is an issue with xdebug not getting the cookie correctly. I can set `xdebug.remote_autostart=true` and then it works, with or without the cookie.

Comment: See what xdebug says about it -- does it even tries to connect when it does not work? If it does not work with cookie -- does it work if you add such param as GET parameter (query string)? Try also clearing ALL cookies in a browser. Check site-specific settings in a browser -- maybe you have accidentally added some "deny" rule for it. Also check what cookies PHP sees in such unsuccessful session.

Comment: Yes if you add it as a query (?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=vagrant) it works ok in a browser, and Postman. I've also tried on various browsers, with and without the cookie. Whatever it is, xdebug simply doesn't pick up the cookie. And yes, I've looked through the logs. It logs access via GET but not COOKIE

Comment: So ... do you see xdebug cookie in the web server log/php variables? Have you thought about trying different version of xdebug (just in case). If browser sends the cookie but xdebug simply does not see it... then I simply have no other ideas then. Maybe it's your web server .. that does not let that cookie to go through or some Vagrant/VM specific thing?

Comment: It's the same version of xdebug (2.2.5) that I've been using for a while :(